# Has the Twin Paradox Really Been Resolved? Interesting peer-reviewed paper states that it hasn't been resolved

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, time, observers, time-dilation

Has the Twin Paradox really been resolved? Here is an interesting peer-reviewed paper [*Has the Twin Paradox Really Been Resolved?*](https://dx.doi.org/10.4236/jamp.2021.99138) ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/354318351_Has_the_Twin_Paradox_Really_Been_Resolved)) which states that it hasn't been resolved:

Of particular interest is this example of the twin paradox which shows the standardly accepted "resolutions" do not work (please see the linked paper for the diagram and more interesting examples):

> 3.1. Twins Approaching Each Other  :
>
> 3.1. Twins Approaching Each Other   Consider twins, A and B, both initially at rest with respect to an inertial frame and separated by
> distance d. They synchronize their clocks according to the fol-lowing
> method. When the clock of twin A reads 0At=, she sends a light signal
> towards twin B. This light signal takes a time dc to reach twin B. So,
> when twin B receives the light signal, she sets her clock to Bt dc=
> [2]. Then at a time that the two twins had previously agreed upon,
> they start moving towards each other with equal accelerations relative
> to an inertial frame O at their mid-point. The accelerations are very
> large but take place in a very short time (essen-tially a Dirac δ
> function) resulting in relativistic speeds. The two twins then start
> moving towards each other, each with a constant speed v relative to
> the other, as shown in Figure 2. According to twin A, twin B is moving
> with speed v. Therefore when they reach each other at the midpoint O,
> the clock of B should show a shorter time than the clock of A, i.e.,
> tB < tA. On the other hand, according to twin B, twin A is moving with
> speed v. Therefore when they reach each other, the clock of A should
> show a shorter time than the clock of B, i.e., tA < tB.

> In this
> situation, the system is completely symmetric; neither twin leaves her
> reference frame, and both have the same initial acceleration.
> Therefore, none of the suggested expla-nations can resolve the paradox
> in this case.

How would you resolve the above instance of the twin paradox, as well as the othe examples given?

Comment: Sorry I am suggesting to close this post, this is about new research, this is not what PhysicsSE is about.

Comment: Scientific Research Publishing is a predatory publisher, which solicits papers via spam email and has no meaningful peer review, despite its claims to the contrary. While it is not strictly *impossible* for a good paper to be published there, I would suggest approaching any of those papers with a healthy degree of skepticism. This one, for example, is based on a misunderstanding of a topic covered in Physics 101, which may well be shared by some professional physicists but is certainly not worthy of publication.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing here.

This paper claims that the twin paradox hasn't been resolved because you can set up a scenario in which A's and B's conventionally synchronized clocks **do** read the same thing in the same place after a journey.

The paradox in the twin paradox is that A's and B's conventionally synchronized clocks **don't** read the same thing in the same place after a journey (which, being counter-intuitive, is helpful for isolating a place where common intuition fails to comport with the model that predicts reality).

Comment: I would even argue that intuition doesn't fail in the twin paradox. One can arrive intuitively at the correct (asymmetric) answer without any reference to math. What I don't understand is why we aren't teaching the proper intuition right from the start, even in classical mechanics, i.e. in Galilean spacetime.

Comment: @flattermann I'd be interested in seeing a curriculum summary that you think would build better intuitions, if you have one.

Comment: The only "change" required here is to introduce the student to the Doppler effect as the actual physical expression of Lorentz transformations. What we are observing is a red/blueshift, not time dilation. In this case both observers see the exact same Doppler shift, but the onset of the Doppler frequency change is immediate for the accelerating twin while it is delayed for the stationary twin. The traveler receives more clock ticks than the homebody and hence sees him or her age more. Alternatively we could teach proper application of Poincare transformations, of course.

Comment: There is no possibility for this scheme to explain the twin paradox.

Comment: There is no need to explain _anything_ because there is _no paradox_.

Comment: @m4r35n357 I concur. For a long time now I have been hoping to encounter someone who agrees that there is no paradox. The twin scenario is counterintuitive to the human psyche, but in and of itself counterintuitive does not a paradox make. What counts is that SR is free from self-contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

There is a long history of people 'refuting' special relativity when in fact they have simply misunderstood it. In the example you have cited, if twins with synchronised clocks, initially far apart and at rest to each other, accelerate and coast toward each other, when they meet, their clocks will be synchronised still. That is true. However, each will still believe the other has been time dilated. There is no paradox or inconsistency here- the person who wrote the paper simply misunderstands what time dilation is. Specifically, they overlook the fact that after the twins have accelerated, their clocks are no longer synchronised. To illustrate the point, let's suppose the twins accelerate at 12:00 and coast towards each other, meeting when their clocks each show 14:00, and let's suppose the speed of approach is such that a time dilation factor of 50%  applies. Twin A will see that Twin B's clock reads 14:00 when they meet, and will conclude that Twin B has been time dilated by 50% because in Twin A's frame Twin B started their journey at 10:00. Twin B will adopt a symmetrical view. They will consider Twin A to be time dilated by 50%, because in Twin B's frame Twin A started their journey at 10:00. So each twin will consider the other to have completed  4hr journey (ie from 10:00 to 14:00) while only recording 2hr on their clock (ie from 12:00 to 14:00).

Comment: As a former member of the IEEE, I would like to formally apologize for this embarrassing episode: https://mathpages.com/home/kmath120/kmath120.htm